# Print empty value if the patterns is empty

Tags: java, regex

I have this Java pattern match code:

```
                out.println("<tr>");
                out.println("<td>" + file_path+ "</td>");
                out.println("<td> .sql </td>");

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<key>([\\w]+)?): (?<value>(.+)?)");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
                while (matcher.find())
                {
                    if (matcher.group("key").equals("author")) {
                        out.println("<td>" + matcher.group("value") + "</td>");
                    } else {
                        out.println("<td> N/A </td>");
                    }
                }
                out.println("<td> date </td>");
```

Do you know how I can print " N/A " if there is no value found into `matcher.group` or `matcher`? Currently the table cell is cut.

Comment: If I correctly understand, your problem is that the code in while loop is not executed? Because the if-case would give you an empty cell with N/A /Could you also add current output and expected output?

Comment: empty row or empty cell? if latter, why not set a flag in the loop and check it after the loop?

Comment: The code is executed  but table cell is missing.

Comment: I mean the table cell.

Answer (score 0):

Seems trivial; set a boolean:

```
out.println("<tr>");
out.println("<td>" + file_path+ "</td>");
out.println("<td> .sql </td>");

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<key>([\\w]+)?): (?<value>(.+)?)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
boolean noMatches = true;
while (matcher.find()) {
  noMatches = false;
  if (matcher.group("key").equals("author")) {
    out.println("<td>" + matcher.group("value") + "</td>");
  } else {
    out.println("<td> N/A </td>");
  }
}
if (noMatches) {
  out.println("<td> N/A </td>");
}
out.println("<td> date </td>");
```

and then you can clean it up by a lot:

```
out.println("<tr>");
out.println("<td>" + file_path+ "</td>");
out.println("<td> .sql </td>");

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("author: (.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find()) {
  out.println("<td>" + matcher.group(1) + "</td>");
} else {
  out.println("<td> N/A </td>");
}
out.println("<td> date </td>");
```

Comment: One question. I have several values to find similar to`if (matcher.group("key").equals("author")) {` But for some reason only the first one is found. Any idea why?

Comment: Your regexp eats the entire string in the value component, probably. I know you tried to configure it as non-greedy, but that only works within a single find() run, not across find()s. You need to exclude whatever separates values from the next key. If it's a newline, for example ([^\n]+) for value instead.